# What are the options for Rewarded Video Ads if one developing game in WebGL within Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, rewardedvideoad

I searched internet and there were not any useful links. Some said to use Ad Sense but i think it is against facebook policy if it is to be published to FB Canvas(Correct me if i am wrong). Are there any plugin that are available? Or Is there any way to set it up externally outside unity and reference them using `Application.ExternallCall`.

Answer (score 0):

Unity official developers said that unity is and will support only mobile ads for the foreseeable future: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ads-for-webgl.311126/ The only alternative solution is to use APIs of the website you are publishing on. So you can check something like this: http://blog.kongregate.com/kongregates-rewarded-video-api/ or even Facebook Unity API for developers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/

Sorry if i don't have provided useful info, but it's the only thing i found.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate kongregate rewarded video apis into unity webgl? As you mentioned Facebook unity Api, i checked their documentation, It seems they provide facebook audience network for ios and android inside unity. I would like to know if it's possible to integrate their audience network into unity webgL?